# SQL Server 2008 overwrite old customer number in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `user_table` that looks as follows:

```
ID   CustID  F_Name   L_Name
01   10122   John     Smith
02   05258   Peter    Down
03   16258   Sam      Wright
```

and another `New_IDs` table

```
Old_CustID     New_CustID
10122           02548568
05258           26894536
16258           00582658
```

and I would like to have a script that will find `Old_CustID` in `New_IDs` table and will replace `CustID` in `user_table` with `New_CustID` from `New_IDs` table.

We have about 6000 users. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - piece of cake :-)

```
UPDATE dbo.user_table
SET CustID = new.New_CustID
FROM New_IDs new
WHERE
   dbo.user_table.CustID = new.Old_CustID
```